# Potential bug in heapq.heappush?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand if the following snippet doesn't exhibit a bug in heapq.heappush :

```
import heapq

x = []
heapq.heappush(x, 1)
print(x)
try:
    heapq.heappush(x, "a")
except:
    pass

print(x) # [1, 'a']
```

Here, I'm trying to build a heap with non-comparable items. As expected, the second call to heappush is throwing an exception. However, I notice that the second item was inserted in the array anyway. This array was supposed to always contain a heap, and now it isn't a heap anymore.

**Shouldn't heappush method undo the insert of "a" in case it can't finish the heapify process on insertion ?**

Consider the case where you have a multi-threaded system relying on this. Assume I have some workers that are dequeueing from the heap, and some worker processes that are inserting in the heap. This means that if a worker is incorrectly inserting an invalid type, the worker will raise an excpetion as expected, but the underlying data-structure is still corrupted

Comment: My best guess is that because `heapq` is only intended to provide an *algorithm* for priority sorting and not a *data structure* for a heap, it doesn't attempt to take care of the state of your data structure if the algorithm fails. Kind like a "bring your own object" situation. I suppose you could subclass list and only allow values of the same type to be appended.

Comment: I agree with DMalan's comment and [relent95's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75091621/1431750). While it may not be a _bug_ it's definitely a gotcha. **The joys of mutable state.** This is a consequence of iterative mutation operations. And occurs in other languages as well. [Kotlin's `mapKeysTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-keys-to.html) updates the target Map (dict) iteratively; and if an exception is caught, the [target has the results up until then](https://pl.kotl.in/ytJmkUY7M) rather than it's pre-operation state.

Comment: You are facing the danger of dynamically typed languages. Fortunately, there is the `typing` module which can help you to prevent those errors, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html. So just define `x: list[int] = []` and run a type checker like `mypy` on your code to avoid this situation.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue specific to typing, but purely how the heappush function handles exception within its implementation

Comment: Here, I mean that you should try to avoid the situation where you compare strings with integers at first place. In typed languages this will not happen, because the compiler may complain at compile time. In python such a clear programming error can crash your application all of a sudden at runtime, e.g. your server goes down after 1 week and you are just left with some logs and need to figure out what happened. Here, `typing` with a type checker will act like the compiler and complain before running into that issue.

Comment: In can happen for other reasons though, you could have the same type in the list, and a  complex custom comparator that throws an exception

Comment: @CarlosHorn It can happen in Strongly Typed languages too. [Here's an example in Kotlin](https://pl.kotl.in/ytJmkUY7M) which I posted in a comment above. The loop is controlled by the library function, not by me and when the NullPointerException occurs, the target map `upperFruits` has an incomplete result; rather than empty as it was before the call `mapKeysTo` call. This is a consequence of iterative mutation operations, and less to do with Typing. Although, typing helps to mitigate such things, the focus here is that it can happen easily due to coding errors, and has side-effects.

Answer (score 3):

Although it may be opinionated to some degree, I believe most other Python veterans will agree with me.

No it's not a bug. When an exception occurs in a function or method, there's no guarantee that the state of the variables is restored to the previous one. You can also see this for the core API `list.sort()` in the following example.

```
a = [2, 1, 4, 'a', 4, 3]
try:
    a.sort()
except:
    pass
print(a)
# This will output "[1, 2, 4, 'a', 4, 3]".
```

As a side note, putting non-comparable objects into a priority queue is an abnormal operation, usually a mistake by a programmer, which is a candidate for an assertion. If the library has to handle this case, it will be inefficient for the users because most of the time the additional code will be dead code and will be a burden to the maintainer.

Comment: Good example of "happens everywhere"  +1

Comment: `If the library has to handle this case` you could argue that the point of providing such function is first to be correct, then fast.
As a sidenote, if you check the implementation of PriorityQueue (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/queue.py#L236) it is itself a client of heapq.heappush yet it also doesn't do the checks either

Comment: A famous example from Python's FAQ: [Why does a_tuple[i\] += [‘item’\] raise an exception when the addition works?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works) @lezebulon